# Intuition on the overall entropy increase caused by heat transfer

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Let's say that Hotter Gas A loses heat to Colder Gas B. Heat is transferred from A to B in such a way that the overall entropy increases. This can be proven with equations, but what is the intuition behind the increase in entropy? How are there a higher number of microstates after this heat transfer? I think that there will be a wider distribution of gas particle speeds, but I am not too sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your Hotter Gas A consistsing of very tiny $\color{red}{red}$ balls, and your Colder Gas B of very tiny $\color{blue}{blue}$ balls. For the sake of simplicity let there are $\color{red}{\mathrm 3\ red}\ $balls $\color{red}{A_1A_2A_3}$ and $\color{blue}{\mathrm 2\ blue}$ balls $\color{blue}{B_1B_2}$, and let microstates are their different sequences..

Before mixing them together, microstates comprises only from different arrangements of **red** balls, and different arrangements of **blue** balls. For example, $\color{red}{A_3A_1A_2}\color{blue}{B_2B_1}.$

After mixing them together, there are more microstates, not allowed before, e. g. $\color{red}{{A_3A_1}\color{blue}{B_2B_1}A_2}.$

Comment: I feel like the OP is more interested in the energies and/or speeds rather than the spatial distribution. Or am I misunderstanding the analogy?

Comment: @AaronStevens, every analogy lags behind the reality, not excluding mine one. I answered by analogy the OP question “How are there a higher number of microstates after this heat transfer?”

Comment: I understand analogies aren't perfect. What I mean is that the OP didn't ask about mixing the gases, they asked about heat transfer between the gases. The result is the same (more microstates), but I am not sure if the OP was interested in the microstates based on the spatial arrangement of the particles. And perhaps your example has an obvious link to energies to someone who has thought of these things before, but I am unsure if the OP will be able to make this link.

Comment: @AaronStevens, we will see the OP's reaction, then will be time to adjust the answer or provide another one (maybe by someone more experienced than I am).

Comment: If heat was transferred by radiation, then the particles wouldn't be mixed up. I am indeed more interested in the energies/speeds and less in the spatial distribution of particles.

Comment: It's only analogy. Red balls may be particles of originally hotter gas, with higher energy. What I illustrated as spatial, is the distribution of energy. The idea behind it that there are much more possible distributions of energy, if the energy of individual particles is clustered near **one** value, as with energy clustered near **two** (substantially) different values.